# help on version-control for legacy code

Tags: svn, version-control, solaris, legacy-code

I'm looking for some kind of backup/version-control method for a legacy system:

- Systems are developed in a version of BASIC.  It's an interpreted version.  Programs are saved in some pseudo-code; not pure text.
- All production programs are stored in the same folder tree, divided into folders depending on the category.
- No subversion strategy, apart from storing the previous version of the program being modified into a subfolder named **old_versions**.  There is one **old_versions** subfolder within every category folder. Example: **/programs/accounts_payable/old_versions/**
- Programs are modified on the fly, **in the production environment**.
- System run on a Solaris server

**I would like some method of real-time backup of, every program modified, stored in a separate location.**  Nothing fancy.  It doesn't need to do rollbacks or change-comparisons.  It just needs to **SAVE THE MOST RECENT VERSION OF THE PROGRAM**.

Thanks.

PS:  Yes, I'm really angry and desperate.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your development process, perhaps one way would be to use rsync or similar in a shell script to take snapshots every xx minutes, and send them to another location.

I think the best solution would be to migrate to a VCS, personally I'd recommend git or svn, and stop editing code in production. You can always `svn export` to get a clean tree if needed.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Tivoli might be something for you.

I have purchased it in the past for about 50$. It monitors changes to files/folders you have setup and writes a copy (or delta, I don't know) to a location you specify.

I wish I could give you a link to the program but after fighting 5 minutes with the IBM website (again) I gave up in frustration. Their products are solid, their website or methods to purchase them are, well, not.

Answer (score 0):

If software is being modified on the fly in the production environment I'd humbly suggest that real-time backups are not the solution to your woes. It potentially solves a faulty outcome while completely ignoring the root cause.

Comment: That I know, but thanks.  I prefer to have at least something, then start from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at rsnapshot; see http://www.rsnapshot.org/. It can make multiple snapshots of a directory tree, using hard-linked files to save space where a file hasn't changed.